# C# Func<T, bool> vs Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: c#

In C#, given that:

- `IEnumerable<T>` declares `Where(Func<T, bool>)`
- `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`
- `IQueryable<T>` declares `Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>>))`

When using this:

```
var list = new List<int>();
var positives = list.AsQueryable().Where(x => x > 0);
```

How does the C# compiler distinguish between both methods?

Comment: ["Closer is better"](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/).

Comment: The standard rules of method resolution apply. `list.AsQueryable()` has type `IQueryable`, so `IQueryable.Where` is used. If you tried the same thing with both methods declared on the same type, the call would be ambiguous.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I agree, but why is `x => x > 0` closer to `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` than `Func<T, bool>` ?

Comment: @Spiff It isn’t. If both methods were defined in the same class, the overload couldn’t be resolved (try it). You’re asking the wrong question. Read the article. Or mm8’s answer.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of `Where` that accepts an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` is an extension method of `IQueryable<T>` and since `IQueryable<T>` extends `IEnumerable<T>`, it will be chosen first due to the overload resolution mechanism in C#.

Please refer to @Jon Skeet's [article](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Overloading) on the subject for more information:

> If there are two methods at different levels of the hierarchy, the "deeper" one will be chosen first ...

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is correct, isn't it?